# Can we transform back calendar adjusted forecast?

Tags: time-series, back-transformation

I've monthly data, I adjusted it for monthdays and conducted a forecast. After that can I adjust it back and compare it with untransformed time serie?

Comment: Can you tell us some more details? How do you want to backtransform?

Comment: Let's say: adjust time series to 30 days, forecast, adjust resulting time series to corresponding months. Hence the mean value will refer to real non averaged months length. My question is: could this "backtransform" affect the result in any way?